# difference between symantec command line pgp encryption & other pgp encryption tool like iGolder,GnuPG etc

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, gnupg, pgp, symantec

what is difference between symantec command line pgp encryption and other pgp encryption tool like `iGolder`,`GnuPG` etc.

Is it possible that a file pgp encrypted by `symantec command line` that can be decrypt by other tool like `iGolder,GnuPG, bouncy castle` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In general, compatibility between various OpenPGP applications and libraries is achieved by using the algorithms defined in the RFC 4880. This means that if Symantec PGP follows OpenPGP standard and doesn't use proprietary patented extensions (they do exist), the resulting file would be handled by other applications.

The other thing to check is that the algorithm used by the originating application is supported by the software that decrypts the file later. For modern versions this is not an issue, but some companies use the dated versions of PGP software, which doesn't handle some of the newer algorithms. In this case you can have an issue.